# What does 'template item<float>();' in C++ PyTorch front end mean?

Tags: c++, pytorch

In the official PyTorch C++ [example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/cpp/custom-dataset/custom-dataset.cpp) , there is this bit:

```
  float Loss = 0, Acc = 0;

  for (const auto& batch : loader) {
    auto data = batch.data.to(options.device);
    auto targets = batch.target.to(options.device).view({-1});

    auto output = network->forward(data);
    auto loss = torch::nll_loss(output, targets);
    assert(!std::isnan(loss.template item<float>()));
    auto acc = output.argmax(1).eq(targets).sum();

    Loss += loss.template item<float>();
    Acc += acc.template item<float>();
  }
```

I am curious what this idiom means:

```
    Loss += loss.template item<float>();
    Acc += acc.template item<float>();
```

**Why not use just `loss.item<float>()`?** Is this specific only to PyTorch?

Comment: The `<` in `loss.item<float>()` is the less-than operator (and then the token sequence is a syntax error), but in `loss.template item<float>()` it is the opening bracket of template arguments.

Comment: @j6t OP is confused about the use of `template` keyword, not about the template argument list.